# How can I force my Dataset using application to reconnect and prevent timeout error?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-2.0, dataset, timeout

### Brief question

What command can I use to make my DataSet refresh it's connection to the SQL Server before I go on to work with the DataSet object?
I'm working with C# in .Net 2.0

---

### Much longer version of the same question with specifics

I have a database application that is often left running for several hours between manually instigated operations. When returning to the application after a long period (> 1 hour) and clicking a button it will throw a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with the error message

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I figure I have a few options here:

- increase the timeout
- force the application to close after it has performed it's operation ensuring that the app is always started afresh when a user wants it.
- test the health of the connection before performing each operation.

My preference would be the latter but I don't know where a connection can be invoked or tested. I'm using Visual Studio to drag-drop build my DataSet, creating an instance. Filling tables and passing the dataset to another form. It is when loading this other form that the exception is thrown, but only if the application is left idle for hours.

I have not managed to replicate this in debug mode as yet, but I think the exception is likely being thrown by the `_dsDistrib.tblReport.DefaultView.Sort`line of the child forms constructor below.

So how can I make sure this DataSet has an active connection, or force a new connection, before I try to use the DataSet?

Relevant code of the main form

```
    public frmMain(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dsDistrib = new dsDistrib();
        taDistrib = new ReportShunt.dsDistribTableAdapters.tblDistribTableAdapter();
        taDistrib.Fill(_dsDistrib.tblDistrib);
    } 

    private void btnManage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new frmManageDespatch(_dsDistrib,taDistrib).ShowDialog();
    }
```

Constructor of the child form

```
    public frmManageDespatch(dsDistrib ds, dsDistribTableAdapters.tblDistribTableAdapter taDis)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dsDistrib = ds;
        taDistrib = taDis;

        _dsDistrib.tblReport.DefaultView.Sort = "tblReportId";

        dtUsers = (dsDistrib.tblUserDataTable)_dsDistrib.tblUser.Copy();

        cboReport.DataSource = _dsDistrib.tblReport;
        cboReport.DisplayMember = _dsDistrib.tblReport.ReportNameColumn.ColumnName;
        cboReport.ValueMember = _dsDistrib.tblReport.tblReportIdColumn.ColumnName;

        lbxUserSelection.DataSource = dtUsers;
        lbxUserSelection.DisplayMember = dtUsers.OutputFolderColumn.ColumnName;
        lbxUserSelection.ValueMember = dtUsers.tblUserIdColumn.ColumnName;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: from your comment, I'm now guessing taDistrib is a SqlDataAdapter that is populated from a library called ReportShunt.  The library is responsible for opening the connection.

Assuming that the table adapter has a select command, you could close the connection like.  The table adapter would normally open it itself, before it talks to the database:

```
private void btnManage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    taDistrib.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
    new frmManageDespatch(_dsDistrib,taDistrib).ShowDialog();
}
```

You can also grab an entirely new connection:

```
private void btnManage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var localDsDistrib = new dsDistrib();
    var localTaDistrib = new ReportShunt.dsDistribTableAdapters.
         tblDistribTableAdapter();
    taDistrib.Fill(dsDistrib.tblDistrib);
    new frmManageDespatch(localDsDistrib,localTaDistrib).ShowDialog();
}
```

Better yet, only keep the connection open when you're actually doing something with it.  Connections get cached and reopening them has no overhead at all.  (We measured it with millions of request, and couldn't find a noticaeble difference.)

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was looking for but I can 't find "Connection" in autocomplete under the instance _dsDistrib nor as a static method under dsDistrib? I'm working in .Net 2.0, is a later feature?

Comment: Then dsDistrib is probably not a DataTable.  Maybe you can add the type definition to the question?

Comment: _dsDistrib is a DataSet of the type dsDistrib. I've checked under my table instances _dsDistrib.tblDistrib and the the table definition dsDistrib.tblDistrib and cannot find a Connection property. I also checked under the DataTable class (unrelated to my DataSet) and can't find it there. 
Do you mean DataSet or DataTable, I'm a little confused and might be missing something obvious.

Forgive my ignorance, I'm very new to programming, but is the type definition, the autogenerated code built by VS when I place the tables on the dataset designer? I can post this but it is over 1300 lines!

Comment: What's the extension of the file where you place tables using the designer?  Dbml?

Comment: .xsd it displays in the solution explorer as "dsDistrib.xsd".

Comment: Recreating the TableAdapter _seems_ to be better than before. I have still had the timeout error when the application lies idle for a long time but have never replicated the issue in debug mode. If I get a better / more definite solution I will update the answer futher